# What is the volume bound by $x^2+y^2+z^4=1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I saw this question on an old exam for my calculus course, and I can't get anything (Mathematica, Matlab, etc.) to plot me a graph of the function. I'm not quite sure how to setup the triple integral to calculate the volume of this solid.

Comment: Should be able to draw a surface parametric plot using spherical coordinates. Somewhere between a sphere and a cylinder.

Comment: I think you can use the following parametrization: $x=\rho \cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, $y=\rho \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$ and $z=\rho \sqrt{\cos(\phi)}$, with $\phi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2],\theta\in[0,2\pi[$. You get $\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{\cos(\phi)}}$ for the jacobian... (set $\rho=1$)

Answer (score 2):

Technique due to Dirichlet, the volume in the first octant ($x,y,z \geq 0$) is
$$ \frac{\Gamma(3/2) \Gamma(3/2) \Gamma(5/4)}{\Gamma(1 + (1/2) + (1/2) + (1/4))}   $$
so the whole thing is $8$ times that.

Meanwhile, $$ \Gamma(3/2) = (1/2) \sqrt \pi  $$ and
$$ \Gamma(9/4) = \frac{5}{4} \Gamma(5/4),   $$ reciprocal is $4/5,$ so I get one-eighth of the volume as
$$  \frac{ \pi}{5} $$ and all as
$$  \frac{8 \pi}{5} $$

Turns out the volume inside
$$ x^2 + y^2 + |z|^n = 1  $$ is
$$ \frac{2 \pi n}{n+1}  $$
Should be no trouble integrating using polar coordinates, but have not tried yet... Yep, easy in polar.

Comment: is there a material to learn the dirichlet technique in detail thanks

Answer (score 1):

Plotting the surface in *Mathematica* is straightforward:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^4 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Slice it into pieces of constant $z$.  Between $z$ and $z+dz$, there is a circle of radius $\sqrt{1-z^4}$ and area $pi(1-z^4)$.  Integrate this from $z=-1$ to $z=1$.